# jqPlot drawing Piechart issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

I've faced the next problem: when i get data and try to build an jqPLot PieChart, the firebug says `uncaught exception: No Data`
here is my function for data retrieving:

```
function getValues(){
        var myArr=[];

        $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : myUrl,
                data : {

                },
                success : function(response) {
                    for ( var i = response.myList.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                        var obj = response.myList[i];
                        var id = obj.id;
                        var name = obj.name;
                        var value = obj.value;

                        ......some code here....
                        myArr.push[{name:value}];

                    }
                },

                error : function(response) {
                    alert("your request cannot be handled. " + response);
                }
            });
            drawPieChart(myArr);
}
```

and here is my drawPieChart function:

```
function drawPieChart(array) {
     var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chartdiv', [array], 
                { 
                  seriesDefaults: {
                    // Make this a pie chart.
                    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                    rendererOptions: {
                      // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                      // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                      showDataLabels: true
                    }
                  }, 
                  legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
                }
              );
}
```

and here is html source, where I want to insert my PieChart:

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
```

so can anyone help me with this issue? what I'm doing wrong?
all files for jqPlot are connected correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqPlot only takes in [[[X, Y], ...]]

So change myArr.push({name: value}) to myArr.push([name, value])

See http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/pie-donut-charts.html

Answer (score 0):

the way you feeding the data is wrong try hard coding it like below:

```
var data = [
['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 
['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]]
```

with some simple values and see if you can get it running if it works then work around that.